# Refresh the list box data when we come back from previous activity

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox, windows-phone

I have 3 screen A,B and C, In screen A i am populating the data from xml and passing it to Screen B using the below method :

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MyObject"] = listOfTopics; // Passing list which has all topics.
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ScreenB.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I Screen B i am receiving the List and using that i am displaying list of items in the list box.

```
 List<MyTopics> listOfTopics = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["MyObject"] as List<MyTopics>;
```

UI screen B:

---

Text ----------9

---

I select some item in from List box in Screen B and move to next screen C,Now the value which is towards right changes. like 13 or to some value.When i click on back button from Screen B it will come back to Screen A.Now the data which i am having in Screen A is not refreshed.

I have used onNavigatiedTo() where  i am calling the same method which is populating the data.

But the applicaton crashes here because its not able to find the List of objects -listOfTopics .

How to fix this ?

Comment: State is not persistent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx
Try @bit suggestion with ApplicationSettings[]

Comment: No need to use PhoneApplicationService in your case, use of static list may solves your problem.

Comment: @Jaihind How ?, and please have a look at here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502518/pasing-nested-array-using-linq-to-xml

Comment: Set KeepAlive property as false for the screen 1

Comment: @petchirajan keepAlive where ?

Comment: For your PhoneApplicationPage

Comment: I am not sure.. I don't know how you implemented the navigation. just try it..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Passing-Data-between-Pages-958ee09b/sourcecode?fileId=92261&pathId=1560034782).

I cannot oversee your entire application, but it might be that recipe 4 from the example, application level data, is the one you are looking for.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   ...
   public List<MyTopics> ListOfTopics { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

You can then access it from your pages by using

```
(App.Current as App).ListOfTopics
```

Or maybe even better is to make it an ObservableCollection and bind it to your list(s).