# Pasing nested array using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have xml like the below:

```
    <array>
    <dict>
          <key>Topic</key>
          <string>ABC</string>
          <key>Items</key>
          <array>
            <dict>
              <key>Header</key>
              <string>Data One</string>
              <key>Content</key>
              <array>
                <string>This is how we parse the data.</string>
                <string>This is how we parse the data.</string>
              </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
              <key>Header</key>
              <string>Data Two</string>
              <key>Content</key>
              <array>
                <string>I am now able to parse the data</string>
                <string>I am now able to parse the data</string>
              </array>
            </dict>
    </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
          <key>Topic</key>
          <string>ABC</string>
          <key>Items</key>
          <array>
            <dict>
              <key>Header</key>
              <string>Data One</string>
              <key>Content</key>
              <array>
                <string>This is how we parse the data.</string>
                <string>This is how we parse the data.</string>
              </array>
            </dict>
            <dict>
              <key>Header</key>
              <string>Data Two</string>
              <key>Content</key>
              <array>
                <string>I am now able to parse the data</string>
                <string>I am now able to parse the data</string>
              </array>
            </dict>
 </array>
    </dict>
    </array>
```

I have many dict like this.

This is how i am doing it:

```
List<Note> NotesList = (from plist in doc.Root.Element("array").Elements("dict")
           select new Note
           {
                MainTitle = (string)plist.Element("string"),
                ListOfSubTitles = plist.Element("array").Elements("dict")
                                       .Elements("string")
                                       .Select(s => (string)s)
                                       .ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Here MainTitle is ABC,

Subtitle is Data One and for each subtitle we have array of items which i need to parse?

How can i modify the above to add the `Key Content` values as well.

Comment: There is no `dict` element in inner array

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy No its just this <key>Content</key>
          <array>
            <string>I am now able to parse the data</string>
            <string>I am now able to parse the data</string>
          </array>

Comment: is your xml string is correct ???

Comment: thats just sample data that i have added

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You got what i am trying to acheive here ?